# Supabase SessionContextProvider causes unnecessary re-renders

Tags: next.js, supabase

Following Supabase's [Next.js Quickstart](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/getting-started/tutorials/with-nextjs), after logging in the index page re-renders everytime I:

- Switch from another browser tab back to my application's tab
- Switch to full screen mode
- Switch from full screen mode back to window mode.

Tested on Mac OS Safari and Chrome. According to the profiler tool, it is `SessionContextProvider` that causes the updates. It also causes the view to flash a lodading state, because Account page fetches user data on every render.

First I would like to get rid of this behavior where the view re-renders when the user is switching between tabs and full screen modes.

Second, I want to consider if the session should be fetched server-side, although this might be a topic for another post.

The example project is found [here](https://github.com/supabase/supabase/tree/master/examples/user-management/nextjs-ts-user-management).

Comment: You might be interested in [this example](https://github.com/supabase/auth-helpers/tree/main/examples/nextjs-server-components) using Next server-side components.

Comment: My app doesn't use the `app/` directory/server components at this point, although this could change in the future.